# Is this a valid question?

Tags: discussion

On the Christianity website, are we allowed to ask, "is **_** a sin?" If we do ask such a question, are we supposed to specify a specific audience, ie., catholic, Mormon, etc.?

Comment: This very issue has actually come up before: [What to do with "Is x a sin" questions?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1486/58). Also, for most questions, you are expected to specify a specific audience, like you say, so that answers can be more focused, more objective, and less likely to become a voting contest.

Comment: @El'endiaStarman Why don't you close as dupe?

Comment: Check out the [question types that the community finds acceptable.](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/types-of-questions-or-template-questions-that-the-community-generally-finds-ac) I think I mention "Is x a sin?" in there.

Comment: I guess not exactly but they fall under "Also, questions without a frame asking for what is true ("Truth questions") are off-topic."

Comment: @fredsbend: Went ahead and did that, thanks to your suggestion.